# Is there any technology to kill the user login session if user close the browser?

Tags: session, browser, jakarta-ee

This should work if multiple windows are open.

My application is in J2EE.

I already tried some javascript like on window.unloadn but this kind of solution is not solid.

Comment: Session cookies (ie. cookies that expire at the end of a session, ie. when the browser is closed)?

Comment: @stakx That just removes the session cookie. It doesn't take care of the session data in the database (which I guess is what the OP wants)

Answer (score 5):

If you mean on the server side, the best way is to implement a heartbeat. If none of the windows from this webapp are open, nothing sends a heartbeat, and a server after some time will know the app is disconnected.

If you mean on the client side, there's no 100% reliable way, since the browser might die from external causes (kill/crash/reboot), but a timed-out cookie that is updated regularly in a heartbeat-like fashion might work

Answer (score 4):

HTTP is a stateless, meaning you can't tell when a browser is closed.

Your attempt to use `window.onunload` does not always work because the browser could exit before executing your event handler.

The technology used to find out if a user has closed their browser (or a best guess) is to use timeouts. Sessions will automatically timeout (this is configurable) - in asp.net the default is 20 minutes. If there is no activity, the timeout kicks in.